# Sharepoint 2007, linking two sharepoint sites

Tags: navigation

In my company, each department has it's own sharepoint site. My site has my departments information. Another department has their information on their site but would like to link to a page on my site. Pretty much, we would like to click on the left hand navigation and have my site open in the same window. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can add link to the other department site(s) the left hand navigation by going to Site Actions | Site Settings | Quick launch

Answer (score 0):

The Look and Feel section in Site Settings allows you to configure the left hand navigation (called Quick Launch for some reason - it operates at the same speed as other links of the page ;-) and the top link bar. Both are just sets of normal hyperlinks that can link to any site, as long as you can reach it of course.